# Trying to access and edit a Wix Text Element that's inside an iframe - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml, velo

everyone! Hope y'all doing fine.

In a nutshell: I have a Wix page that we can call "main page". Inside my "main page" i have two iframes, one called "input iframe" and another one called "output iframe". The "output iframe" loads inside of it another embedded page, the "insurance page". This "insurance page" has a Wix text element #s80copqc.

What I'm trying to do is to get the "main page" code to send a postMessage to the "output iframe" and edit the Wix text element #s80copqc that's located inside the "insurance page" (that loads within the "output iframe").

I think its simpler than it sounds lol, although I'm not sure it's possible...

I've tried everything from var to innerHTML and nothings worked so far... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.